# sedgwick quick find algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm new to algorithms and was hoping someone could explain why Robert Sedgwick talking about quickfind algorithm said:

> "And I mentioned that a lot of us would get us wrong.  The mistake we
>   might make is to put ID of P here rather than first picking out, that
>   value.  And you can think about the implications of that. That's an
>   insidious bug."

Why we have to put "pid" instead id[p]??
About what bug he said?

Here is a code:

```cs
public class QuickFindUF {
private int[] id;

public QuickFindUF(int N) {
    id = new int[N];
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        id[i] = i;
        }
    }

public boolean Connected(int p, int q) {
    return id[p] == id[q];
    }

public void Union (int p, int q) {
    int pid = id[p];
    int qid = id[q];
    for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
        if (id[i] == pid) { //"id[i] == id[p]" is not correct! Why?
            id[i] = qid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the value that `id[i]` holds changes based on the current loop iteration. `id[p]` refers to the number in the `id` array at index `p`, but inside the loop you set the value of `id[i]`. So it's possible that while the loop is executing, the value `id[p]` gets overwritten. That's why you save a copy of that value outside of the loop, in the `pid` variable.

Comment: Why not ask the person who you are quoting.  How do you think random people on the internet are qualified to clarify someone else's words?  Though that never stopped the internet before.

Comment: Sam Axe, because I rely on person's authority. I don't think he will answer to this question. https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/

Comment: nbokmans, thanks a lot :)